# Is it possible for the power of the deity in a temple to get diminished for whatever reason?

Tags: temple

Can it get diminished for whatever reason?

Comment: You should add your main question in the body.  Title is not the entire question. Title is just the introduction whereas your question should be in detail in the body. It should not be a single line. Please modify your question.